# Get the duration of the video file in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, image-uploading

Currently i am working with a video uploading functionality. The requirment is to show the length of the video before playing the same. SO is there any way to get the length of the video in CF. Also need to show the thumbnails of that particular video in the browser.

Thanks in advance for the help....

Answer (score 2):

I used ffmpeg.exe to get all the information about video in coldfusion.

Try `<cfexecute>` with http://ffmpeg.org/

Command that should work -

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_streams inputFile.mp3 | grep duration | cut -f2 -d=
```

More details about ffprobe -

http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Writers